# Does amazon have an official Ruby client to manage ec2, s3, etc?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ruby

I like how rackspace has: http://packages.python.org/python-cloudservers/index.html

Is there something simliar in Ruby for aws?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of official Amazon Ruby libraries but see [Amazon Ruby Developer Center](http://aws.amazon.com/ruby/) for community Ruby libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the ruby [AWS SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/).
Instead EC2 you can try [EC2 ruby gem](https://github.com/grempe/amazon-ec2) from the community libraries

Comment: here the link to the [community libraries](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/kbcategory.jspa?categoryID=173)